# Image url in code-behind not working using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database

I have a problem with displaying images in my website using asp.net. Originally I have it all working successfully when i haven't integrated yet a strongly typed data control in my repeater. Here is the code previously:

```
public void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    Image img = e.Item.FindControl("brandImage") as Image;
    img.ImageUrl = "../Images/Guitar Brands/Guitar Items/" + 
      ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["itemimage1"];
}
```

The code above works perfectly when im still using datasets. But when i started using strongly typed repeater, it gives me this server error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.
>   stringInstrumentItem_F14A58FE0974F90187F45D6
>   203769613D21C52F3672B47D240863DC806C87C17' to type 
>   'System.Data.DataRowView'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the   current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information   about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object
>   of type   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.
>   stringInstrumentItem_F14A58FE0974F90187F45D6203769613D21C52F3672B47D24086
>   3DC806C87C17' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 26:     {   Line 27:         Image img =
>   e.Item.FindControl("brandImage") as Image;   Line 28:
>   img.ImageUrl = "../Images/Guitar Brands/Guitar Items/" +
>   ((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem).Row["itemimage1"];   Line 29:     }
>   Line 30:
>
> Source File: c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\GuitarItemsFront.aspx.cs    Line: 28
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies. 
>   stringInstrumentItem_F14A58FE0974F90187F45D6203769613D21C52F 
>   3672B47D240863DC806C87C17' to type 'System.Data.DataRowView'.] 
>   Pages_GuitarItemsFront.repeater_ItemDataBound(Object sender,
>   RepeaterItemEventArgs e) in c:\Users\User1\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\WebSites\MusicStore\Pages\GuitarItemsFront.aspx.cs:28 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnItemDataBound(RepeaterItemEventArgs
>   e)   +111  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateItem(Int32
>   itemIndex, ListItemType   itemType, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem)
>   +138  System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.AddDataItemsIntoItemsArray(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean useDataSource) +217 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.PostGetDataAction(IEnumerable
>   dataSource) +71 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.CreateControlHierarchy(Boolean
>   useDataSource) +220 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnDataBinding(EventArgs e) +62 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.DataBind() +77 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.EnsureDataBound() +58 
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +15 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +88 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160 
>   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +160 
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +883

The error is pointing towards the image path. I want to know how to make my image url work again with strongly typed data control in repeater. I will include also the code for the aspx file.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="repeater_ItemDataBound" ItemType="stringInstrumentItem" SelectMethod="GetItemData">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="one-two">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="linkButton" OnClick="Repeater1_OnClick" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Item.brandId + ";" + Item.model %>'>
                 <asp:Image ID="brandImage" runat="server" ImageUrl='<%# Item.itemimage1 %>' height="130px" width="350px" />
             </asp:LinkButton>
            <div class="content">
                <div id="label"><%# Item.brand.name %> <%# Item.model %></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Also to get an idea what my database is, here are the tables:

Table stringInstrumentItem(The column brandId is the foreign key and references the primary key of table brand, which is also named brandId):

itemId  brandId  model

1         1            xyz

2         1            abc

3         2            hjk

Table brand(which has the primary key called brandId that is referencing by the table strinInstrumentItem):

brandId  name  image

1         Ibanez    xyz.jpg

2         Fender    abc.jpg

3         Gibson    hjk.jpg

Here is also the code for GetItemData Method:

```
public List<stringInstrumentItem> GetItemData()
{
    MusicStoreDBEntities obj = new MusicStoreDBEntities();
    List<stringInstrumentItem> name = new List<stringInstrumentItem>();
    name = (from g in obj.stringInstrumentItems where g.brand.name == guitarName && g.type == "Guitar" select g).ToList();
    return name;
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `e.Item.DataItem`?

Comment: This has nothing to do with images. `e.Item.DataItem` isn't a `DataRowView`, it's an entity type named `stringInstrumentItem` (subclassed by Entity Framework for lazy loading) as the error indicates. Cast to that type instead.

Comment: How do you assign data to DataSource? Could you also show us the query?

Comment: @Win - i have included the code at the end of the question.

Comment: @CodeCaster - could you please show me how to do it?

Comment: Replace `DataRowView` in `((DataRowView)e.Item.DataItem)` with `stringInstrumentItem`...

Comment: @CodeCaster - yup, i have already figured it out. I never knew i could access it that way. Beginner mistakes.

Comment: I hope this won't get downvoted tho. I have really indicated there complete details of my problem and this will help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use ***Include*** keyword in query. *For example,*

```
List<stringInstrumentItem> name = obj.stringInstrumentItems
        .Include(x => x.brand)
        .Where(g => g.brand.name == guitarName && g.type == "Guitar")
        .Select(g => g)
        .ToList();
```

Then remove ImageUrl from markup, and assign that from code behind.

```
<asp:Image ID="brandImage" runat="server" height="130px" width="350px" />
```

Code Behind

```
protected void repeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var stringInstrumentItem = e.Item.DataItem as stringInstrumentItem;

        Image img = e.Item.FindControl("brandImage") as Image;
        img.ImageUrl = string.Format("~/Images/Guitar Brands/Guitar Items/{0}", stringInstrumentItem.brand.image);
    }
}
```

***Note***: If possible, do not have space in folder name.

Comment: hmm..actually the query is working. I have already solved it by changing the cast in the image url from DataRowView to stringInstrumentItem. But i'm interested in your approach, this will also work.

Comment: Normally, we use Include keyword to *explicitly load* the relationship tables. EF sometimes does the great job of pulling those tables for us automatically, but it is not always the case.

Comment: I see. great insight.